# MediaWiki API section names encoding

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding, mediawiki, url-encoding

For **[[Test#?]]**, I get "**Test#.3F**" from `action=parse` bit of MediaWiki API. What is this encoding and how do I bring it to human readable format using [Perl](http://www.perl.org)'s [CPAN](https://metacpan.org)?

[URI::Encode](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEncode) works for the percent decoding, but not the section names one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but the `?` is `0x3F` in ASCII, and `U+003F` in Unicode. Perl's `ord` function returns the codepoint of the first character in a string, while the `chr` function reverses that. I. e. something like `s/\.[A-F0-9]{2}/chr $1/eg` will handle a few cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is UTF-8 percent-encoding, but with `.` instead of `%`, and spaces replaced with underscores; additionally, multiple consecutive whitespaces are collapsed, and `:` is preserved (not encoded into `.3A`).

The exact code which handles it is [Parser::guessSectionNameFromWikiText()](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/includes/parser/Parser.php#L5633), but if you do not want to dig through a lot of code, check the much simpler implementation in an older MediaWiki version (compatible except for a few edge cases), in [anchorencode()](http://phpxref.com/xref/mediawiki/includes/CoreParserFunctions.php.source.html#l174):

```
str_replace( '%', '.', str_replace('+', '_', urlencode( $text ) ) );
```

Comment: Written in Perl terms, this would be: `$str = uri_encode($text); $str =~ tr/%+/._/; $str`, the reverse being `$str =~ tr/._/%+/; uri_decode($str)`.

Comment: Do you know what the edge cases are?

Comment: @svick: wiki or HTML markup in the section title. Actually, the parsing of wikilinks and section headings is slightly different: if you just want to simulate `[[#...]]`, you only need to decode HTML entities, but if you want to match the anchor generated by `== ... ==`, you need to do some more special processing. (Also, I expanded the answer with some not-so-edge cases I found out.)

Comment: @Gryllida, per [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#h-6.2) allowed characters in an id are alphanumeric, `.`, `:`, `-` and `_` so they had to replace `%` with one of them.

Comment: @Gryllida There is no name for such encoding, because it's specific for MediaWiki. I don't know about any other site that uses this “dot-encoding”.

Comment: FWIW in MediaWiki docs this is called anchor encoding. Few other software bothers to offer stable section linking from external sites to content whose structure can change radically, so the problem of encoding anchors does not come up often. HTML5 allows just about anything in IDs, so MediaWiki will probably eventually migrate to a simpler encoding method.

Comment: @Gryllida: yeah, it is a strange choice not to encode the `.`. Anyway, duplicate section titles are allowed in MediaWiki, so the problem is more widespread (section titles containing `.3F` are probably not too frequent). The software just adds `2` to the second id in such cases.

Comment: We should erase all comments and add them into the answer body to follow the QA format.