# Stop MediaWiki encoding parentheses in section anchors

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting, mediawiki, urlencode

I recently installed MediaWiki 1.23.9 on a HostGator-hosted server (Apache-based I believe). I got it all configured and got pretty URLs up and running, got action URls also rewriting properly and everything was nice. I noticed, however, that anchor links, specifically the auto-generated section headers, aren't quite so pretty. They undergo "dot encoding" for some reason I'm not 100% sure on.

This results in `/w/MyPage#Section_1_(Stuff_Here)` becoming `/w/MyPage#Section_1_.28Stuff_Here.29`.

With parentheses being valid URI characters (and in fact, if used in a page title, they are properly not encoded in the URI), I don't understand why this is happening, nor how to stop it. I looked through all manner of bug reports and even tried glancing through the MediaWiki source. I found the function that performs the encoding, but as far as I can tell parentheses shouldn't be getting encoded.

My question is: Is there a way to prevent MediaWiki from encoding parentheses in section header anchors? Failing that, can I mask this behavior using .htaccess rules? For reference, my current .htaccess file is below, though I would very much prefer turning it off rather than masking it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

**Note:** [This answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146448/140810) provides a quick explanation of what the "dot encoding" process is, though not how to exclude parentheses from it.

Comment: Try [`$wgExperimentalHtmlIds`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgExperimentalHtmlIds).

Comment: @Tgr Worked like a charm! Re-post that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki encodes section ids to honor [HTML4 restrictions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name). This is a relic of the past as MediaWiki uses HTML5 these days, which removed those restrictions. You can set [`$wgExperimentalHtmlIds`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgExperimentalHtmlIds) to true to make MediaWiki follow HTML5 rules (where only whitespace needs to be converted).

This is called "experimental" because at the time (the setting was introduced in 2010) browser support for HTML5 was somewhat unreliable. Today that's probably fine but no one actually tested that so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks! The bit of background around the option is quite interesting too!